# Keep some values (based on the id) if a condition in another column is respected

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this, and I would like to write a code in order to keep some rows based on the time. It need to keep all the rows of an id if a certain value of time is reached (e.g. 5).

```
id <- c(rep(1, 5), rep(2,4))
time <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4)
amount <- c(10,20,40,50,60,12,20,32,42)
e <- cbind(id, time, amount)
e
```

For example, in this case, I would like to keep all the rows of `id == 1` because its time reaches 5.
Since time never equals 5 for `id == 2`, its rows would be deleted.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hey, if any answers have solved your question, please mark the preferable one as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: If you are not sure about it, please read [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/412699).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this by creating a flag:

```
library(dplyr)
id <- c(rep(1, 5),rep(2,4))
time <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4)
amount <- c(10,20,40,50,60,12,20,32,42)
e<- data.frame(id, time, amount)
e
#Compute
e %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(Flag=max(time,na.rm=T)) %>%
  filter(Flag==5) %>% select(-Flag)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   id [1]
     id  time amount
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     1     10
2     1     2     20
3     1     3     40
4     1     4     50
5     1     5     60
```

Answer (score 1):

Or in base R:

```r
e[e[,"id"] %in% names(which(tapply(e[,"time"], e[,"id"], max) >= 5)),]
#>      id time amount
#> [1,]  1    1     10
#> [2,]  1    2     20
#> [3,]  1    3     40
#> [4,]  1    4     50
#> [5,]  1    5     60
```

Comment: If `id` is not sequential, e.g. `id <- c(rep(2, 5),rep(4,4))`, your code doesn't work.

Comment: @DarrenTsai you're right, though we can just add `names` around `which` and it will work in that case. Will update. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A `base` solution:

```
e <- data.frame(id, time, amount)
subset(e, id %in% id[time >= 5])

#   id time amount
# 1  1    1     10
# 2  1    2     20
# 3  1    3     40
# 4  1    4     50
# 5  1    5     60
```

---

The corresponding `dplyr` version:

```
library(dplyr)

e %>% filter(id %in% id[time >= 5])
```